# How to auto clicking a link with referral or auto redirect a link with referral?

Tags: javascript, html, redirect, referrer

How to auto clicking a link with referrer or auto redirect a link with referrer?
As I have tested,  using location.href and location.replace will not pass referrer to next page. Any method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can go through this

```
      <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="N; URL=other-web-address">
```

where N is the approximate number of seconds that you want the current web page to be displayed before the browser automatically goes to the other web address. If N = 0, then the browser should go immediately to the other web address.

for more details check [here](http://www.pa.msu.edu/services/computing/faq/auto-redirect.html)

or you can also use this

```
   <HTML>
   <script>

   function autoChange()
   {
   var timeID = setTimeout("location.href= 'http://www.xyz.com'", 1000)
   }
   </script>
  <BODY onLoad="autoChange()">
   Welcome to my website,... unfortunally we moved it to WWW.xyz.COM.<BR>
   Your browser will automatically jump there.<BR>
   If it doesn't then please click <A HREF="http://www.xyz.com">here</A> to go there.
   </BODY>
   </HTML>
```

Comment: both methods I have tested before, and I can't get the referrer using these 2 methods

Comment: I have tested the 2nd one in firefox,crome and ie8 it works fine.

Comment: I have tested again, and it should be https problem causing my page cannot pass the refferer, any idea of passing refferer in a https page to an http page?